# Generate synthetic images from a 3D model of an object

Tags: rendering, pose-estimation

I want to carry couple of tests to evaluate the accuracy of a pose estimation algorithm that I am working on. I have a 3D model of some objects and would like to generate synthetic images of this object at various known poses.

For someone being new to computer vision, which method/tool i can use to generate synthetic images.

Comment: If you have access to a camera and can place your objects in known positions, why not just take pictures of objects in known positions? Otherwise, to generate images objects with exact poses you need to have an exact 3D model of your object. Sounds like your path of least resistance is to take pictures of objects and place them in known positions in the physical world.

Comment: I already have a 3D model of the object that I am trying to detect and estimate its pose. I was wondering how to generate synthetic images using this 3D model.